# Why do we write arr + n in sort function?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
sort (arr, arr + n)
```

Why do we write `arr + n` in sort function in (function in algorithm library) `C++`. What does it mean `arr + n`?

Comment: @DanielLangr, yeah sorry, probably got some things mixed up. I was thinking about `int a[n]` like stuff, which is probably non standard.

Answer (score 4):

1. [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) accepts iterators to beginning and end of some range (end points to first element beyond range).
2. A pointer can be an iterator
3. In `C` an array of type `sometype[n]` [decays to a pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array#Array-to-pointer_decay) of type: `sometype*`. So `arr` is treated as a pointer and `arr + n` advances this pointer by `n` elements (so it point to first element beyond array).

Now alternative ways to write this code to make it more clear and less bug prone:

```cpp
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));

// or using C++20 ranges:
std::ranges::sort(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the declaration of `type arr[]`, the expression `arr + n` is evaluated as the address of the `n`th element in `arr`.

In other words (hoping that it helps clarifying), `arr + n` is equivalent to `&arr[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) takes a pair of iterators and them uses `std::swap` to sort the elements in that range.
The iterators must provide implementations for `operator*` and `operator++`. These requirements are defined as "named requirements" [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

If you thing about it, any pointer fulfills these criteria.
In other words, you can think of iterators as a generalization of pointers. By passing a pointer to the first `&arr[0]` and a pointer to one past the last element `&arr[n]` you are providing the begin and end iterators. `arr` and `arr + n` are fancy abbreviations for `&arr[0]` and `&arr[n]`.